# Please suggest approach for Java-based web app

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm a Java developer that hasn't coded in about 5 years and wants to polish up my skills. I am going to create a small app that uses an OAuth 2.0 authentication flow and then makes a few REST calls and displays the results. I've got my credentials setup with the OAuth provider.

I used Eclipse back in the day, is that still a solid IDE for this type of project?  If I want to share the app with others to show my work, where could I host the code?

Thanks for these and any other pointers.

Comment: Is your app intended to run in a desktop or mobile environment?
Generally, Eclipse is a good idea, but you might want to use a different IDE depending on your application specificities. As for hosting code, Github is generally a good option, as long as you are familiar with `git`.

Comment: Never used git although I generally get how it works. It will be desktop environment.

Answer (score 1):

first off - yes, Eclipse if still a good choice.

if you can, make you app a web-application, and then you can host it in PaaS such as [Google AppEngine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/). then the **app itself** will be always accessible from any machine that is connected to the web. this way, you will be able to show it to anyone you want.

if you only want to show the **code**, then [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [Google Code](https://code.google.com/) are a good choices.

HTH